# Timing problem in C

Tags: c, logic, constraints, real-time

I dont have good experience on c... i just want to learn some of the practical scenarios to be implemented in c.... for example how can i implement the following in C code...

y=1 when x=1
y=0 when x!=1

the main thing is that....

output **y** changes when input **x** changes and has to maintain its state for **1 second** if there is any change in the input within 1 sec it has to maintain its previous state.

please any one help me on this..and kindly help me how to approch for this type of logics.. please

Comment: This sounds more like a VHDL/Verilog problem...

Comment: @Matt: I'd say temporal logic, but that shows my theory background.

Comment: Woods (1989) [Temporal logic case study](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/reports/89tr024.pdf) gives an idea of how temporal logic is used to model these kinds of constraints, with the obligatory elevator running example.

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford busy waiting when `x` isn't changing, then

```
volatile int x;
int old_x, tmp = x;
while (1){
    y = ((old_x = tmp) == 1);
    Sleep(1000);
    while(old_x == (tmp = x));
}
```

if you have any event or interrupt when it's changed, it can be done without busy waiting.

Comment: The qner was also after general thoughts on coding these kinds of example.

Comment: @Charles: it's almost all that C could do about VHDL's delay. Generic case should be tough..

Comment: +1 for using volatile. jack needs to develop on this. The part that's not mentioned in the question but is obvious is taking the input (which would require multithreading/multiprocessing).

Answer (score 0):

Once you figure out how you want to handle IO and timing, these are possibilities for the relevant test:

```
y = (x == 1 ? 1 : 0);
```

or:

```
if (x == 1) 
    y = 1;
else 
    y = 0;
```

or:

```
y = 0;
if (x == 1)
    y = 1;
```

Comment: This doesn't treat the IO constraints in the qn at all.